# Joomla component + friendly url

Tags: php, joomla, seo

I'm new at Joomla. I just had made my first component and module. I use _GET parameters such as 'page', 'nr' and 'q' (q contains _POST parameters in base64) because I made my own pagination. So, when I try to use it on Joomla it works fine and the url without SEF looks like this:

**http://mydomain/?option=com_mycomponent&view=test&page=0&q=[base64]**

But what I want is to make it friendly. I think it should something like this:

**http://mydomain/component/mycomponent/view/test/page/0/q/[base64]**

I enabled SEF in joomla and when I print JRequest::get('get') it just appear **option** and **itemid** parameters. What should I do to get the rest of them?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define routing in your component. That should give joomla what it needs to output what you're requesting. http://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

There are also other SEF plugins that attempt to do this across your whole Joomla site, but they don't always work 100%.